# how to read event fullcalendar with google calendar, and calendar id google save on table

Tags: javascript, php, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

How to read the data calendar en Google stored in the database, to view fullcalendar integration with fire Google calendar?

JS fullcalendar:

```js
ar a ='<?php echo $class_id?>';
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#event').fullCalendar({
            aspectRatio: 2.4,
            googleCalendarApiKey: 'AIzaSyC-Fax449D0FdfSBiRaSGHfw3leXKxD0E4',
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            allDayDefault: false,
            editable: false,
            events: {
                url: "events/" + a ,

            },

            timeFormat: 'H(:mm)' ,

            });
        });
```

Controller call to calendar address id:

```js
public function events($class_id)
{
$this->load->model('event_model');
$events = array();
$e = array();
$data['google'] = $this->event_model-> list_event_google_class($class_id);
foreach ($data['google'] as  $value) {
  $arr = array
  ('googleCalendarId'=>$value['google_calendar_id'] );
  }
  echo json_encode($arr);

}
```